# Using Slice With Array Created By Knockout's Mapping Plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've been struggling with this all day and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I have a working grid created using Knockout. I'm trying to convert the grid to use the mapping plugin and it breaks my paging. How do I use the slice function with the mapping plugin to return a subset of my array? What am I missing?

```
var grid = {};
grid.Model = function (jsondata) {
 var viewModel = {
  items: ko.observableArray()
 };

 $.getJSON('/api/test/items', function (data) {
  viewModel.items= ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
 });

 viewModel.itemsOnCurrentPage = ko.computed(function () {
  return viewModel.items.slice(1, 10);
 }, viewModel);    
};
```

I'm attempting to bind to itemsOnCurrentPage (foreach: itemsonCurrentPage). Binding directly to items works fine. This worked when I was manually building my array on the client side. Now I'm grabbing the data via jQuery and using the mapping plugin. I can't figure out what I'm missing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you wire up a JSFiddle to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RP is correct.

Here is a JSFiddle that shows what you are doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/P99zy/

Here is an update that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/P99zy/2/

The only difference is the way I load the table items.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that the `itemsOnCurrentPage` computed observable is bound against your original observableArray.  When you do `viewModel.items = ko.mapping.fromJS(data)`, you are setting `viewModel.items` equal to a new observableArray (one that `itemsOnCurrentPage` is not bound against).

You can instead do: `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModel.items)` to update the existing observableArray.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I understand what I'm doing wrong. Now I need to figure out a solution. I don't want to update viewModel.items. I just want to show a 'slice' of viewModel.items.

Comment: You can definitely still use `itemsOnCurrentPage`.  You just want to update the existing observableArray when your AJAX request returns.